# Maps vs Google Maps data consumption

Tags: iphone, ios, maps, google-maps

Out of Apple's Maps (or just - Maps) and Google Maps, **which is more economical on data?**

Google Maps caches the path to destination. I know this because I have searched for locations on Google Maps and then turned my phone data off. It still takes me there, minus the traffic updates.

On Maps, I have no idea myself and also there is no information about data usage online.

The specific cases I'm looking answers for:

- Going to an address in the same city, which is better in terms of data usage?
- Going to another city, which is better in terms of data usage?
- What features can I sacrifice in one or the other so that I can get the most information with least data usage?

---

**Update:** I noticed recently that Apple Maps has also started caching. If you start the directions to a location and then turn data off, Apple Maps too takes you there. However, I have seen this only when going to a place close by. Not sure of the behavior when going to a distance farther away - like going to another city altogether.

Comment: I have no concrete information, but I remember reading the following information. First, Apple Maps uses vector images, while Google used to use bitmaps on Apple but Vector on Android. I believe that Google added Vectors in iOS after they were kicked off. Second, Apple maps has always been able to cache the map data en route, which was one of its best features.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder how it is with apples look around? hope it will be released for the whole US soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was [a study](https://www.whistleout.com/CellPhones/Guides/How-Much-Data-Does-Google-Maps-Use) about it recently and it compared the data used on average for 10 miles and for 20 minutes driven.

Google Maps uses the less data, 0.67 MB every 10 miles and 0.73 MB every 20 minutes on average.

On the other side, Apple Maps uses 1.33 MB every 10 miles and 1.83 MB/20 minutes.

If you want to use less data you should turn off trafic data and satellite view.

I’ve tested caching for long trips <60 miles and it worked in both apps, so you can use the one you prefer!